# Visual Studio 2010: Replacing text in a project item through automation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I automatically instantiate Visual Studio project items through the object model. In some files I need to do text replacements. What is the best approach to do text replacements on the contents of a project item (an xml file for example) using the object model, so Visual Stuido takes care of required source control action. I prefer not to open the file into the editor, and do text replacements through the editor object model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [TextDocument.ReplacePattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.textdocument.replacepattern.aspx) method. You can get TextDocument object from the ProjectItem object like this:

```
DirectCast(ProjectItem.Document.Object, TextDocument)
```

The complete code is as follows:

```
Dim pi As ProjectItem = ...
Dim win As EnvDTE.Window = Nothing
If Not pi.IsOpen Then
    win = pi.Open(Constants.vsViewKindPrimary)
    'uncomment the following line if you want to show opened document
    'win.Visible=True 
End If
Dim td As TextDocument = DirectCast(pi.Document.Object, TextDocument)
td.ReplacePattern("abc", "def")
If Not win Is Nothing Then
    win.Close(vsSaveChanges.vsSaveChangesYes)
End If
```

Comment: No. In fact, if the document is not opened in the editor, the ReplacePattern method throws an exception. You need to open the document invisibly in the background, perform replace and then silently close the document. The code in VB .NEt is as follows:

Comment: Thanks Peter, going to implement this.